# angular js get selected value from object in array with ng-options select inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

i need a help to solve my case.
i try to make a table form that perform calculation using angularjs. in this case contain a chaining dropdown selection that achieved by using filter. its working fine when i only put the ng-options there. but when i try repeating the select option inside ng-repeat, i cant get the value of my selection.

i have problem defining the ng-model for each ng-options, because in somecase the chaining filter will break if i rename it.

please take a look my code and help me to find what is missing, or refer me to the article or some tutorial with same case like mine.

thank you

Here is the app
[plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/O4A7NRWaXq9G6kABJPMz)

Json data

```
[{
"id":"AP-01",
"productName": "Art Paper",
"category": "Paper",
"subCategory": "Common Paper",
"height": 100,
"width": 65,
"thickness": 0.3,
"weight": 110,
"color": "White",
"unitPrice": 800,
"images":
  [
    {"full": "/app/data/images/image.gif"},
    {"thumb": "/app/data/images/image.gif"}
  ],
"availablePurchase": "true",
"canView": "false"}]
```

the ng-repeat:

```
<tr ng-repeat="option in selectedMaterials">
```

ng-options:

```
<select ng-model="selectedCategory" 
        ng-options="material.category as material.category for material in materials | unique: 'category' | orderBy:'category'">
       <option value="" ng-value="undefined">Choose Category</option>
</select>
```

and the next quesion how can i get the each value of my selection if i have a combine option on my dropdown, code below:

```
// Combine Size Option Function (height x width)
        $scope.combined = function(size){
            if(size.height === undefined || size.height === ''){
                return size.width;
            }
            else {
                return size.width + " X " + size.height + " cm ";
            }
        };
```